# How to reset K3s cluster pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, k3s, kubernetes-cluster, kubernetes-container

I have a k3s cluster with following pods:

```
kube-system   pod/calico-node-xxxx                          
kube-system   pod/calico-kube-controllers-xxxxxx   
kube-system   pod/metrics-server-xxxxx
kube-system   pod/local-path-provisioner-xxxxx
kube-system   pod/coredns-xxxxx
```

How can I reset (stop and start the pods again) the pods either with command (`kubectl` maybe) or any script?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: to get to the starting/basic config of pods like coredns, metric-server etc. I want to simply reset the cluster which means stop and start the containers in one go. is there any command to do that ?

Comment: Not really, you'd need to write a script.

Comment: For any of those pods you can just `kubectl delete` them and they will automatically be restarted (I think all of them are managed by a Deployment resource).  You could do this in a single command pipeline with something like `kubectl get pods | ...filter to get just the name you want... | xargs kubectl delete pod`

Comment: To add to @larsks comment - you can get just the names of the pods with `kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}'`

Comment: @Pawel-:: kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}' command is not giving any output

Comment: @larsks-:: ...filter to get just the name you want... : how to filter the pods ? do I need to write any grep command for full podname eg:  kubectl get pods | grep "coredns-7448499f4d-k2zt4" | xargs kubectl delete pod

Comment: @solveit, seems you don't have any pods in `default` namespace. To display pods from different namespace add `-n` flag to the command e.g.: `kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o=jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}'`. grep-ing exact name of the pod defeats the purpose of piping and `xargs`

Comment: @PawełGrondal-:: By this command all pods of kube-system are coming in output. So what is the point ? I want to restart the cluster. Command " kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o=jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}' | xargs kubectl delete pod" is giving following error for all 5 pods, 5 times:  Error from server (NotFound): pods "coredns-7448499f4d-k2zt4" not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reset a pod, you can just delete it. If it's managed by deployment (pods in your question should be), they should be recreated automatically.

```text
kubectl delete pod <pod-name> <pod2-name> ... -n <namespace>
```

If the pods you want to reset, have common label, you can filter them with `--selector` flag

```text
kubectl delete pods --selector=<label-name>=<label-value> -n <namespace>
```

However, if you changed the deployments somehow, you will need to apply the unmodified manifest.

```text
kubectl apply -f <yaml-file>
```

Comment: @p10I-:: I dont want to write each podname manually. and for restart I am looking for one single command or script. which can stop and start all pods again

Comment: I updated my answer. I don't believe there is any other way to do this other than writing a custom script at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: - This will reset your whole cluster and delete all running data.
This is not the exact answer but best answer. take 1 min only.
Just uninstall by running below command

```
 sudo /usr/local/bin/k3s-uninstall.sh
```

Then install a fresh cluster with below command

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="server --disable=traefik" sh -
```

Then export var using below command

```
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml
```

Also it may complain about some k3s config file access so

```
sudo chmod 444 /etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml
```